# Key features in modern designs

Tags: gui-design, interaction-design

What key features/looks in an application represent a "modern" design?  When you look at an application what gives you the sense of modern?

Comment: I don't mean to seem flippant but a modern design is only modern for brief window of time. It all comes down to trends - the current trend is modern now but the modern trend from 1 year ago is dated. This is a roundabout way to get you define what is "modern".

Comment: Define modern. In European history modern goes back to the end of the 15th century, in fashion it usually goes back about 5 minutes. With web pages...there are any number of rough dates that come to mind for me ranging from almost the birth of the web to the last few months.
I assume you mean towards the more recent end of the scale but even there...no left side menu? No flash? One pagers?

Comment: Wow apparently it has no clear one definition. I do in fact mean the most recent time period with the most recent "technologies."  So as of right now I am talking about the "now."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're question is currently worded, you're asking us to define what constitutes "modern" right this instant, which is like defining "what date it is". The answer will change over time.

If you'd have to define modern as a principle, it'd be defined by anything contemporary. This is a list that's as endless as infinity.

- Aesthetics (colors, shapes, sizes, imaging, animation, etc)
- Interface (buttons, drop-downs, toggles, links, input fields, etc)
- Interaction with peripherals (mouse, touch-screen, phone, fridge, etc)
- Content (Full-HD, 3D, news articles, etc)
- Technology (HTML5, Canvas, JS, CSS, Bootstrap, Drupal, etc)

All of these could have different examples for different points in time.

Modern is a combination of all that, and much more, and always compared to what **was**.